# If $u$ is a unit in $R$. Then is it necessary that it will also be a unit in $R[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $u$ is a unit of $R$, then it means that an inverse belongs to $R$. Thus it belongs to any ring containing $R$. Is there a better answer to this question?

Comment: This is totally fine. Since R is in R[x] u^{-1} is too. However, you might proof that using the definition of a polynomial ring.

Comment: What is $R$? A field?

Comment: @dmtri The context makes it clear that $R$ is a ring, not to mention the letter $R$ which rather suggests that it is indeed a ring.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question [twice](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2897141/29335) making this question's body virtually a duplicate of a comment on that question?  There is no good reason to do that. Please don't do it again.  You might also benefit from reviewing the FAQ about posting on our site.

Comment: @dmtri ....R is a ring.

Answer (score 5):

Your argument is correct, but beware that there might be other units in $R[X]$. For instance, if $R = \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$, then $1 + 2X$ is a unit since $(1 + 2X)(1+ 2X) = 1$.